# IT departments responsiblities standards (Network Admins, System Admins, and Information Security)

Tags: firewall, f5

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. We have an overlapping in the responsibilities between the following departments: Network Admins, Server Admins, and Information Security. The main overlapping is in the F5 and Firewalls devices. I want to ask if there is a standard or best practice for the IT departments responsibilities which we can refer to when we have such overlapping.

Regards,

Comment: A good question, but one that I am afraid may be closed as primarily opinion based. While there are many regulations and standards concerning handling and security of data, I am not aware of any relating to which organizational units should be responsible for various aspect of the administration. This would primarily be because each organization is different and may or may not have the various groups mentioned (and not mentioned) in the question. It is up to the organization to make these decisions.

Comment: If you are looking for standards/regulations concerning this access (and auditing said access), it would be helpful to know what jurisdiction you are in, and what general business use these devices serve (credit card, patient data, power generation, etc). Otherwise there's no way to provide anything but a list and some opinion-based "best practices".

Answer (score 0):

There are many documents on the roles of the IT department.  Some are informative and others are just worth the paper it was written on.  I have spent many years with the military and they have documents that define all roles.  You can use it as a base line for you discussion.  Most security roles start with Network Admins.  The server admins were involved when products like F5 started securing the Application layer of communications.  But most all security personnel were at one time a network person.  They were the ones that blocked all IP's on the router,  then it became a firewall appliance (PIX), now we have several vendors that have similar devices that are basically  the same.

Comment: Thanks James, but is there any published documents regarding this subject?

Answer (score 0):

There will always be overlap between these departments, nearly without exception.  How much that overlap is depends greatly on what the organization is.

Why would your IAO *not* be concerned with what the configuration of your networking equipment looks like?  Insecure SSH configurations, absent port-security config statements, and switch/router versions are all things a security professional's job entails.  The same can be said about servers.  On the flip side, there are portions of the Firewall that might be prudent for your network admins to get involved in (such as passively monitoring traffic).<sup>1</sup>

The IT field is one that requires a great deal of lateral affluence, so everyone is usually all up in everyone else's cool-aid.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In any case, *"Responsibility"* is **not** synonymous with *"Unlimited Access"*.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

NERC / FERC / HIPAA / PCI are all authoritative bodies detailing secure administration of IT systems.  If different departments need different types of access to these devices, look for a multi-level administration facility/feature on these products and TACACS which enables logging of activity per username (RADIUS does not provide this functionality).  Hope that helps.

Comment: why downvote?  just curious?...

Comment: Hi Ron, I haven't down-voted this answer but I can assume that it doesn't really answer, _"Where does each function's responsibility lie"_.  I do believe this answer has hope.  Perhaps detailing how tiered permissions can help achieve different goals might make this more attractive?